How to getAccessToken of microsoft 365 by clientID, tenantID, clientSecret in PHP?
I'm try to use Microsoft 365 account to send mail in PHP.
First, I created a client_id, tenant_id, client_secret, and granted the Mail.Send permission on Azure.
Next, in my PHP code, I used this information to obtain an access token and send an email. However, I keep encountering an invalid_request error during the getAccessToken step.
How to fix this issues?
<?php

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use GuzzleHttp\Client;
use League\OAuth2\Client\Provider\GenericProvider;

$clientId = 'my_client_id';
$clientSecret = 'my_client_secret';
$tenantId = 'my_tenant_id';

$oauthClient = new GenericProvider([
    'clientId'                => $clientId,
    'clientSecret'            => $clientSecret,
    'urlAuthorize'            => 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/' . $tenantId . '/oauth2/v2.0/authorize',
    'urlAccessToken'          => 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/' . $tenantId . '/oauth2/v2.0/token',
    'urlResourceOwnerDetails' => '',
    'scopes'                  => 'https://graph.microsoft.com/.default'
]);

try {
    $accessToken = $oauthClient->getAccessToken('client_credentials');
} catch (\League\OAuth2\Client\Provider\Exception\IdentityProviderException $e) {
    exit('Error: ' . $e->getMessage());
}

Do I miss any information in config?
